# Set dynamic map parameter of @wire method (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a method in my Apex controller that takes two parameters, a String and a Map< String, String>. For the plain String it evaluates correctly for me to pass a variable ‘$myVariable’ and the Apex controller receives the value, but when it is embedded as a value in a map, it doesn’t evaluate it – it just passes the string ‘$myVariable’

LWC JS controller snippet:

```
// strToPass is received from the parent component, ex. "test value"
@api strToPass;

@wire(myApexMethod, {strParam: '$strToPass', mapStringParam:{‘key’: '$strToPass'}})
        wiredInitData({ error, data }){
        if(data){
            this.data = data;
        }
        else if(error){
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

Apex controller:

```
public static void myApexMethod(String strParam, Map<String, String> mapStringParam){
    System.debug(‘strParam: ‘ + strParam);
    System.debug(‘mapStringParam: ‘ + mapStringParam);
}
```

Results of debug statements:

```
strParam: test value
mapStringParam: '$strToPass'
```

**Things I've tried that haven't worked:**

```
// This produced the same results as above:
@wire(myApexMethod, {strParam: '$strToPass', mapStringParam:{key:'myKey', value:'$strToPass'}})

// The Apex method received null here for the map parameter:
mapValues = [{key: 'myKey', value: 'myValue' }];
@wire(myApexMethod, {strParam: '$strToPass', mapStringParam: '$mapValues'})
```

Seems like it's just got to be a syntax issue here, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: could you please create an object. 
`let obj = {'fruit': 'Apple'}
let data = JSON.stringify(obj);`
Change parameter type map to String in apex class, and parse the String in Apex method, could you try with that.

Comment: @sarveshkumar - yes if this doesn't work I can change the Apex method parameter, but I wanted to confirm that I wasn't missing something small before going that route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Added based on comments**

You need to modify the dynamic property `mapStringParam` in change handler of `strToPass` so that wire service is invoked whenever dynamic property is changed. Below is code:

```
@api
get strToPass() {
    return this._strToPass;
}
set strToPass(value) {
    this._strToPass = value;
    this.mapStringParam = { key: this.strToPass };
}

@wire(myApexMethod, { mapStringParam: '$mapStringParam' })
wiredInitData({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.data = data;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

---

**OLD Answer**

When you say `strParam: '$strToPass'` that means `strToPass` is dynamic property but when you say `mapStringParam:{key:'myKey', value:'$strToPass'}`, strToPass is deeply located inside object which will no more be dynamic and it will just consider it as string.

When you want wire service to be dependent on any dynamic property like `myDynamicProp`, it should be directly mentioned with `$` at 1st level:

```
myApexParam: '$myDynamicProp'
```

So, you can change your JS as follows:

```
@track mapStringParam = { key: 'test value' };
@track strToPass = 'test value';

@wire(myApexMethod, {strParam: '$strToPass', mapStringParam: '$mapStringParam'})
    wiredInitData({ error, data }){
    if(data){
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Whenever you change `mapStringParam.key`, it will re-invoke this wire service.
        else if(error){
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas that makes sense. Re-reading this I accidentally left out a part when I was trying to make it simpler to write up and explain here, but the value that I want to pass is actually an @ api annotated property that I'm receiving from a parent component. So I tried to replace the hard-coded 'test value' in the mapStringParam with the "this.strToPass" but the strToPass didn't seem to be populated in time before the mapStringParm was being constructed. I'll update the question, and if you have further thoughts would love to hear!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment correctly.. If this answer solves what you asked in question, then mark this answer solved and ask another question so that comunity can have a look at your query

Comment: What I need is for 'test value' to be a value passed from the parent instead of a hard-coded string. Replacing the string 'test value' with 'this.strToPass' to make it dynamic did not seem to work

Comment: Amazing - your update works perfectly! Thanks so much for sharing!!